# High-level architectural/application infrastructure decisions: where to host a project

Tags: architecture, webserver, cloud, hosting

I've been kicking around this idea in my head for some time now for a product to build in my free time, but whenever I sit down to start actually working on it, I get stuck on this one infrastructural decision that I have a hard time getting past.

## The project

### Audience and purpose

First of all, the product I'm thinking about building would be marketed to hospitals and maybe large doctor's offices in the United States. I don't want to get too much into the details of the problems this software would solve, but suffice it to say that it would provide a way to automate a specific regulatory requirement for healthcare providers in the U.S., which, as far as I know, is mostly currently being addressed manually.

### Requirements

I want this to be a browser-based application. I am most familiar with ASP.NET MVC, so I'm approaching this from that frame of mind, but I would not be opposed to other solutions.

The users of the application would be any hospital employees/staff members. They would only see a version of the application that is set up specifically for their facility - basically it should be a type of intranet site for each facility - and they should be able to use their AD/domain credentials to access their site.

Part of the application would need an integration with the customer's EHR (electronic health records) system. While it could possibly be optional, I would need to be able to access a little of that data to really make it shine. There are many different brands and versions of EHRs, and some more than others make it easier to build 3rd-party integrations. Whichever architectural approach I take, the customer would need to provide the integration piece...it just seems like there would be too many different scenarios for me to try to provide a solution for each one.

### Ideas so far

#### Cloud-based

My first thought was that I'd like this to be something like a multi-tenant application hosted in "the cloud"; however, for the integration, they would probably need to create some kind of REST API  (based on a contract I define) for the app to call to get the data it needs. It seems like most places would be hesitant to do this for HIPAA security reasons. Maybe I'm wrong about that though. I know for Azure, there is [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview), which if used, may let my cloud-hosted app connect to the customer's on-premises resource. But I don't know how feasible or marketable this solution would be.

#### Self-hosted

The other option was to package this up for them to install on their own web server (or as a whole package including the web server), and then provide an interface for them to implement to get the integration piece working. However, supporting this kind of deployment seems like a nightmare.

## The question(s)

- What else am I missing?

  - Is there some other hosting strategy that might work for my scenario?
  - Are there any other pros/cons that I should consider when weighing my options?

Comment: You are asking yourself which hosting option to choose? It's more and more common practice to support both strategies, where small customer are able to use the SaaS cloud version and a larger customer who want own security guarantee and other benefits can self-host.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are planning on a Large Scale business application, Self Hosting might be not the best solution. Yes - in the good old days we did it (in our own infastructure / data centers) and a number of Businesses continue to do it.

The more recent approach is Cloud - for your perticular need i'd suggest a Infastructure as a Service (IaaS) provider where you built a Scalable Application that can be Setup. One such provider is Amazon AWS's Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2).

While having IaaS brings you many advantages it also means you'd need to maintain the Server Side work - such as Security, etc... If you have specific Security Requirements (seems like you do) this could be an opertunity for you to implement your own Security here.

Other Hosting Stragegies includes using a PaaS such as Heroku or Google AppEngine. While you'd not have to deal with Infastruture it may not fully satify your custom security needs.

Eitherway plan to build components that can inteoperate well, that can be replaced or ported. Consider assesing your proposed product in relation with Software Quaity Attributes and make Trade-Offs as needed.

What are you missing...
A lot of things - I'd strongly suggest analyzing how the existing Solutions (in your own helthcare domain) are made. You'll need a very detailed guide / help on Your Architectural plan.